# Insert blank space for copyright at the bottom left part of the first page of ACM paper

Tags: spacing, acm

I'm preparing the camera ready version of a paper published by ACM and I'm supposed to leave a blank space at the end of first column on the first page, so the conference organizers can insert a copyright notice there. How can I achieve this?

The paper is written using the template available [here](http://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template).

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is a crude hack: insert a fake, empty figure with `[b]` placement somewhere on the second column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I wrote [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348254/insert-blank-space-for-copyright-at-the-bottom-left-part-of-the-first-page-of-ac/348269#comment855098_348254), I couldn’t remember whether or not, *e.g.*, `\enlargethispage*{-1cm}` would work as desired in this situation, that is, whether it applies to a single column or not.  Now I have checked that it does.  Here is a compilable example that uses the `article` class, but the solution should be applicable in general.

**Edit:** I’ve just noted that you asked for a space at the end of the end of the *first* column, not the second one!  Well, that’s even easier, since you know in advance where the `\enlargethispage` command should go:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % not necessary, but I like it
\usepackage{lipsum}      % just for the "lorem iipsum..." text

\title{My work}
\author{A. U. Thor}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

\enlargethispage*{-2cm} % use whatever (negative!) amount you need

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

And here’s again the first page of the output:

[image: Output of the code, first page]